# How do I record in an MP4 file format with DXTory?

Tags: windows-8

I want to record in basically any format other than AVI. Avi is an incredibly large file size and just is bad overall for what I do.

MP4 is just an example however I'm down with pretty much any other file type. I'd prefer MP4 but if I can't use that it's still fine.

I *do not* want to switch away from DXTory. I like it, except for the limited format support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you can do is to use another codec when recording.

The steps are provided in the link *(with pictures)*, but I'll write them down here anyway. [DXTory Codec](http://sokosensei.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/how-to-properly-configure-dxtory-h264-encoder-mp3-lame-encoder/)

1. Download the x264 encoder [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/) and Mp3 Lame encoder [here](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/lame_acm_codec.htm)
2. Close DXTory if it's running  and install the x264 encoder
3. Then install the MP3 Lame codec
4. Login in and out / restart the PC, your choice
5. Run DXTory and open the configuration panel
6. Go to ***movie*** section and in ***video codec*** choose ***x264vfw Codec***
7. Click the pencil next to the codec and configure it like the image below [image: Config Page] **NOTE 1: Output mode have to be set on ‘VFW‘ ! Not a ‘File‘.** Click OK to confirm changes
8. Go to the audio setting and configure it like the image below
   [image]
9. You're done! There are some additional instructions on the link I provided if you run into any problems.